# What is the simplest way to attach an external USART to SAM3x8e (Arduino Due)?

Tags: arduino, uart

I need an extra USART on Arduino Due having ability to operate with 9 bits data characters. I have poor knowledge in schematics. I've been searching web for hours but still have no conclusion for the subject.

I know that I2C can be used for this purpose as well as SPI. Also there is possibility to map the USART to external memory bus. (May be I'm wrong)

So what is the simplest option? It would be great to get comprehensive answer, please.

Comment: All the options you have listed are equally hard/simple. I would not go with parallel/memory mapped one though as it will require more "wiring"/pins usage. BTW, I am pretty sure Arduino DUO controller has a capability of working with 9-bit data, it's just that the arduino serial library is crippled.

Comment: I know I created my own serial library, the reason is that I already occupied all the ports on MCU